# Decodificar cadenas con JS

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Tengo problemas al decodificar cadenas como estas "RincÃƒÂ³n de Romos" en JS, utilizando `decodeURIComponent(escape(String))`.
El error es: `URIError: URI malformed`.

Comment: Tu problema no tiene que ver con el URL encode. Los campos los traes de una Base de datos? Revisa que estén guardados en un formato compatible con UTF-8, de ser necesario deberías aplicarle la *collation* necesaria